# Check which radioButton was checked IN ANDROID?

Tags: android

i have a radiogroup and when I check anyone in the group I want to know which one was checked.
Can I give each one an id. 
when I implemented this code

```
  public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
        mChoice.setText(checkedId+"");
    }
```

I was getting some random number.
I was not able to identify which radiobutton I clicked. Is there anyother way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can assign id's like this example from: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-formstuff.html#RadioButtons:

```
<RadioGroup
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_red"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Red" />
  <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_blue"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="Blue" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Then compare `checkedId` to `R.id.radio_red` (use whatever you actually assigned it to be though).